# persist data in a DB issue, receiving NULL on console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I am new to NodeJS and I am having an issue trying to persist/save some data in a DB.

let's start from the beginning so you can understand easier. I have a list of sports with an option to checked or unchecked, that's what I need to persist, that checked.

FRONT END:

**controller.js**

```
$scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) {
  var params = {};
  params.user = $scope.customer.customer;
  sport.checked = !sport.checked;
  SportsFactory.setSportChecked(params);
};
```

**service.js**

```
  setSportChecked: function(params) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.post(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/checked', params)
    .success(function(sportChecked) {
        LocalForageFactory.remove(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED, params);
        defer.resolve(sportChecked);
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        defer.reject(err);
      });
    return defer.promise;
  }
```

I've been debugging this front end part and everything seems to be OK...

Now BACK END:

**setSportCtrl.js**

```
module.exports = {

  setCheck: function(req, res) {
    var checkedSportParams = req.body;

    SportSelectionService.sportChecked(checkedSportParams).then(function() {
      res.json(200, {msg: 'OK'});
    }, function(err) {
      res.json(400, err);
    });
  }
}
```

**SportSelection.js** (model)

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'RedisServer',
  attributes: {
    sport: {
      type: 'array',
      required: false
    },

    user: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

in this part I can see how that `console` are print in the terminal, but if I do `console.log(sportChecked)` or `console.log(newSport)` all I get is an array which says `null` everywhere...

**SportSelectionService.js**

```
module.exports = {

  sportChecked: function(params) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      console.time('sportChecked_findOne');
      SportSelection.findOne({
        user: params.user
      }).exec(function(err, sportChecked) {
        console.timeEnd('sportChecked_findOne');
        var newSport;
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error('Error finding user'));
          console.error(err);
        }else if (sportChecked) {
          newSport =  sportChecked.sport;
          console.time('sportChecked_update');
          SportSelection.update({
            user: params.user
          },
          {
            sport: newSport
          }).exec(function(err, sportCheckedUpdated) {
            console.timeEnd('sportChecked_update');
            if (err) {
              reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
            }else {
              fullfill(sportCheckedUpdated);
            }
          });
          if (sportChecked.sport) {
            sportChecked.sport.push(params.sport);
            console.log('New sport added');
          }else {
            sportChecked.sport = [params.sport];
          }
        }else {
          console.time('sportChecked_create');
          SportSelection.create({
            sport: [params.sport],
            user: params.user
          }).exec(function(err, created) {
              console.timeEnd('sportChecked_create');
              if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
              }else {
                fullfill(created);
              }
            });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

So what do you think is my issue here ? what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: its just that console prints the last value.. if you actually want to see the value of that variable at any point in time.. do `console.log(angular.copy(err))`

Comment: @entre I'll do it but, did you see something wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the whole point of the SportSelectionServices.js to add a new sport to the sports array?

Comment: Also, are you using MongooseJS?

Comment: for starters, your code is impossible to read. Don't nest `.exec` statements, don't mix callbacks and Promises.

Comment: If you are using sails and you can provide some details about how your sails app is set up and what API you have generate I could modify my answer to be more sails-specific.  
It almost looks like you wrote your own backend stuff though?

Answer (score 3):

here is the way I did it, I will teach how from the beginning to the end

starting from the Node.js part, I am using Sails.js and lodash

**SetSportsController.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {

  setCheck: function(req, res) {
    var checkedSportParams = req.body;
    SportSelectionService.sportChecked(checkedSportParams).then(function() {
      res.json(200, {msg: 'OK'});
    }, function(err) {
      res.json(400, err);
    });
  },

  retrieveSetCheck: function(req, res) {
    if (req.params) {
      SportSelectionService.getSportChecked(req.params).then(function(sportChecked) {
        res.json(200, sportChecked);
      }, function(err) {
        res.json(400, err);
      });
    }else {
      res.json(400, {error: 'Error retrieving Sports'});
    }
  }
};
```

than we go with **SportSelectionService.js**

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {

  sportChecked: function(params) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      SportSelection.findOne({
        user: params.user
      }).exec(function(err, sportChecked) {//this array comes with duplicates
        var newSport,
            sportCheckedUniq = _.uniq(sportChecked.sport);//prevents duplicates
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error('Error finding user'));
          console.error(err);
        }else if (sportChecked) {
          newSport = sportCheckedUniq || [];
          if (_.includes(sportCheckedUniq, params.sport)) {
            sportCheckedUniq = _.pull(newSport, params.sport);
            sportCheckedUniq = _.difference(newSport, params.sport);
          }else {
            newSport.push(params.sport);
            sportCheckedUniq = newSport;
          }
          SportSelection.update({
            user: params.user
          },
          {
            sport: newSport
          }).exec(function(err, sportCheckedUpdated) {
            if (err) {
              reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
            }else {
              fullfill(sportCheckedUpdated);
            }
          });
          if (sportCheckedUniq) {
            sportCheckedUniq.push(params.sport);
          }else {
            sportCheckedUniq = [params.sport];
          }
        }else {
          SportSelection.create({
            sport: [params.sport],
            user: params.user
          }).exec(function(err, created) {
              if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
              }else {
                fullfill(created);
              }
            });
        }
      });
    });
  },

  getSportChecked: function(params) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      console.time('sportChecked_findOne');
      SportSelection.findOne({
        user: params.user
      }).exec(function(err, sportChecked) {
        console.timeEnd('sportChecked_findOne');
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error('Error finding sportChecked'));
          console.error(err);
        }else {
          if (sportChecked) {
            fullfill(sportChecked);
          }else {
            SportSelection.create({
              // 10 is the ID for soccer, which must unchecked by default on every single user.
              sport: [10],
              user: params.user
            }).exec(function(err, created) {
              console.log(err);
              console.log(created);
              if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
              }else {
                fullfill(created);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

as you can see here we have only 2 methods, the first

`sportChecked()` is the one which fires up when the user checked or unchecked any of the items.

and then we have `getSportChecked()` which is the method called everytime that the user logs in again.

I do not have any delete method because we are not deleting anything, we are just watching for a change of statement.

Also I am working with a Redis Server

do not forget to create the model, I gave'em a name **SportSelection.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  connection: 'RedisServer',
  attributes: {
    sport: {
      type: 'array',
      required: false
    },

    user: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

also, in the config folder we have **policies.js**, I can't tell you how to work with this because is your configuration, but mine is:

```
  SetSportsController: {
    setCheck: ['jwtAuth', 'sanitizerPolicy', 'headersPolicy'],
    retrieveSetCheck: ['jwtAuth', 'sanitizerPolicy']
  },...
```

then, we go to the **Front End Part** (remember: AngularJS)

I have a controller, **controller.js**

```
$scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) {
  SportsFactory.setSportChecked({
    user: $scope.customer.customer,
    sport: sport.id
  }).then(function() {
    sport.checked = !sport.checked;
    $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
  }, function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
  });
};
```

which is working along this template

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter track by $index"
            ng-click="toggleSportSelection(sport)">
    {{:: sport.name}}
  </ion-item>
```

then, **service.js**

**be aware of AngularJS**

here is where I make the post and get, look

```
  .factory('SportsFactory', function($http, $q, AuthFactory, LocalForageFactory,
                                     LeaguesFactory, ImageFactory, CONSTANT_VARS) {

  getSports: function(customer) {
    var defer = $q.defer(),
    _this = this;

    LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS)
      .then(function(sports) {
        if (!_.isNull(sports)) {
          defer.resolve(sports);
        }else {
          $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/lines/sports/' + customer.agent)
            .success(function(sports) {
              sports = _.sortBy(sports, function(sport) {
                return sport.priority;
              });
              _this.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
                var sportIds = _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
                    intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked.sport);
                if (sports.length) {
                  sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
                    sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);
                    return sport;
                  });
                }else {
                  AuthFactory.logout();
                }
              });
              _.each(sports, function(sport) {
                var sportImg = ImageFactory.sportImages(sport);
                if (sportImg.length) {
                  sport.img = sportImg[0];
                }else {
                  sport.img = 'https://placehold.it/40x40';
                }
              });
              defer.resolve(sports);
            })
          .error(function(err) {
            defer.reject(err);
          });
        }
      });
    return defer.promise;
  },

  setSportChecked: function(params) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.post(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/checked', params)
    .success(function(sportChecked) {
        LocalForageFactory.remove(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED, params);
        defer.resolve(sportChecked);
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        defer.reject(err);
      });
    return defer.promise;
  },

  getSportChecked: function(customer) {
    var defer = $q.defer(),
        user,
        rejection = function(err) {
          defer.reject(err);
        };

    LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED)
      .then(function(sportChecked) {
        user = customer.customer;
        if (!_.isNull(sportChecked)) {
          defer.resolve(sportChecked);
        }else {
          $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/getChecked/' + user)
          .success(function(sportChecked) {
            LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED, sportChecked);
            defer.resolve(sportChecked);
          })
          .error(rejection);
        }
      }, rejection);
    return defer.promise;
  }
});
```

first, center your attention to `setSportChecked()` and `getSportChecked()`, there is where the magic happen in this service, then the function `getSports()` make a called to `getSportChecked()` which looks like this

```
          _this.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
            var sportIds = _.pluck(sports, 'id'),
                intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked.sport);
            if (sports.length) {
              sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
                sport.checked = !_.includes(intersectedSports, sport.id);
                return sport;
              });
            }else {
              AuthFactory.logout();
            }
          });
```

so, this is the end version if this long project, you have to touch lots of file to get with this, to save/persist data in a DB, so, see this code because this is how I have it so far and is working great and is fast, I have no errors yet, parting from here, ask the questions you need to know, I will be answering during the day. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**IF** you are using [mongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/) (it appears you are) **AND** the purpose of the the service is to add the sport to the sports array then you can use the [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) method (which will return a promise with the `exec` method) and significantly reduce the service to:

```
module.exports = {
  sportChecked: function(params) {
    return SportSelection.findOneAndUpdate(
      {user: params.user},
      {$addToSet: {sports: params.sport}}
    ).exec();
  }
};
```

[`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) will only add the value if it is not already in the array. If duplicates are acceptable you can use [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

As pointed out in the comments you are likely using waterline. If so, it appears the `update` method behaves similarly to `findOneAndUpdate`. So maybe this might work (I didn't check if you need to call `exec` or not):

```
module.exports = {
  sportChecked: function(params) {
    return SportSelection.update(
      {user: params.user},
      {$addToSet: {sports: params.sport}}
    ).exec(); // Not sure if this is necessary
  }
};
```

Comment: The question is tagged `sails.js` which means he's probably using [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline)

Comment: @TravisWebb, Ah. It appears you are correct sir. It also appears `update` works in a similar manner though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be done far more simply - rather than updating it like that, just track all your checkboxes client-side and update the whole thing when it changes.

I think you are missing out on some stuff that angular can do for you really easily, and in this case you can push all the workload off on the client rather than the server.

Firstly, make your HTML something like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
      Basketball <input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateRecord()" ng-model="sport.basketball"><br />
      Baseball <input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateRecord()" ng-model="sport.baseball"><br />
      Football <input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateRecord()" ng-model="sport.football"><br />
      Soccer <input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateRecord()" ng-model="sport.soccer"><br />
      Golf <input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateRecord()" ng-model="sport.golf"><br />
      <br />{{sport}}
      <br /><span ng-show="loading">Updating Redis</span>
    </form>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GLc4RtVXkayRsLJZKoZY?p=preview)

Angular will create a sport object for you that will track whatever is or isn't checked.  Rather than trying to manage that inside the database, just let angular take care of it, and whenever it changes, overwrite the whole record.

You can use your toggle function in the ng-change of your checkboxes:

```
$scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) {
  var params = {};
  params.user = $scope.customer.customer;
  params.sport = sport
  SportsFactory.setSportChecked(params);
};
```

On the backend, you can do similarly to what was suggested in other answers:

```
module.exports = {
  sportChecked: function(params) {
    return SportSelection.update(
      {user: params.user},
      {sports: params.sport}}
    ).exec(); 
  }
};
```

This way you have way less code, it's easier to read, and you remove a LOT of logic from the server.

Unless there is some reason I am missing, you don't need to use $q in your ajax call.  You can just use $http built in success and error to handle the promises.

You will need to change your model, by the way, to hold the sport object rather than an array.

Also, if you are in fact using sails, just use the blueprint PUT.  You don't even need any logic - sails has already generated it when you generate your api.

When you load your page, just get the record back, and push data.sport into $scope.sport and your checkboxes should update.

Comment: I can't do it from Angular. I already did it but from the node js part, I am working with users, and I was needing to keep the records of every user, if a used checked a sport, and then he logs out, once he logs in again, the user needs to see the same sports he has checked on his last session, so it is not a thing from the front end part. actually I will posting here tomorrow how did it.